# Setting a connect timeout with PDO working wrong

Tags: php, pdo, database-connection

I'm using PDO to get data off a MySQL server.

```
try{
    $dsn"mysql:host=192.168.201.74; dbname=phonebook"
    $obj = new \PDO($dsn, $this->author['db_user'], 'root',array(
        PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 120,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ))
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();  exit;
}
```

I was set it for 120 seconds, but only after 20 Exception was returned.Why?!

Answer (score 0):

That means that the Exception that is happening is not caused by a timeout. The error is most likely coming from the database server your script is connecting to.

Also, the fact that your code does not show any obvious reason to error out does not help much.

Comment: It returns an exception that takes too much timeout

Comment: Edit your question and copy/paste the exception in it. Unfortunately, it is not helpful at all to just say that it is returning an exception. Exceptions have a code and text message for a reason.

Comment: I only caught that exception when my server failed, I don't know how to make that error right now

Comment: Can you just try again and look at the error and write it down exactly here?